# Hardware Accelerated CSS3 Transitions on Windows Phone Browser

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, animation, css, windows-phone-7.1

I was wondering if anyone knew of an equivalent technology to iOS' translate, rotate, and scale hardware accelerator properties used in CSS3 webkit transitions that I could find in Windows Phone 7 or even Windows Phone 7.1, Mango.

The company I work for creates websites that operate on a variety of mobile platforms.  Currently, we support iPhone and Android devices only, but we're looking to expand our reach to Windows Phones as well.

In the past I used those webkit properties to provide smooth animations for moving around DOM elements in my UI plugins.  jQuery's animate function and even pure javascript just wasn't cutting it.

However, after some research I'm found out that the current Windows Phone 7 doesn't support CSS3 or HTML5.  So my usual methods won't work here.  Fortunately, I've been told that the new 7.5 version should have Internet Explorer 9 on it, which does support some CSS3 and HTML5 technologies.  However, I'm wondering if anyone knows if there are any webkit-like translate, rotate, and scale properties I can use in Windows Phone.

Comment: 7.5 has hardware accelerated HTML5 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deva/archive/2011/04/16/mix-11-hardware-accelerated-html5-ie9-amp-mango.aspx). I'm not sure if there are any special methods you have to call, or if it's done automatically. Source code of these demos might help: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/mobile/

Comment: Thanks for the websites filled with examples :)  I'll definitely study these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, the current Phone (7.0) does not support HTML5 or CSS3. The browser is some sort of IE7 / IE8 hybrid in terms of its functionality.

The good news is that the Windows Phone 7.1 release (mango) will bring with it IE9.0, which is built from much of the same code as the desktop browser. This will brig with it pretty good HTML5 support and hardware accelerated CSS3 transitions, rotations etc ...

You can try out your website right now on the WP7.1 emulator.

Be sure to use the `-ms` CSS prefix in your CSS. Most of CSS3.0 is still in draft so still requires browser specific prefixes.

Comment: Thanks for the info and for telling me about the emulator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402563(v=vs.92).aspx).  I had a feeling they had their own proprietary "-ms" prefix, but it's been difficult finding solid information on WP7.1 html5 and css3 examples and/or tutorials.